# All Ubuntu gnome user input(keyboard) layers?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xkb

Where can I find extensive in depth info about the current standard layers from the keyboard key hit moment to the output interface inside the display (say bash hosted nvim editor) so I can understand all that happens when pressing a keyboard buttin to how the different drivers interperd act and passit between them (xkb ,xmodmad) which are actually legacy(which I mainly want to know all the legacy tools used as a base) drivers, passers and other programmer abstractions and funny names for non standard software structure if there are any.

I'm mostly trying to figure out who are all the middle men between the keyboard and the PC and their doc's to fix some fundamental stuff and customiz.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? The keyboard stack greatly varies. If you want to fix individual keys, you can try `input-remapper-gtk` , which works at the same layer as `evtest`. If you want to fix typing, you can modify an input method system like ibus/fcitx , which has parts loaded into the apps themselves.

Comment: If you want a minimal, text-file-only-editing style, then look in `/usr/share/X11/xkb`

Comment: my goal with the config editing is to stay as close as possible to the source and avoid any 3rd party tools, I've  followed this guide https://camuthig.github.io/posts/remapping-linux-modifiers-with-xkb/ successfully to the point which half worked with the `grp:toggle` opt which did change the keycode but didn't change layer... so I ended up doing it through dconf of gnome wm level and now I'm looking to remap ++ctrl+f1++ - ++f12++ keycombos to F13-63 but I'm not sure where to search for the syntax / api for that so now I'm looking for a clean way to change keycodes of mod-key-combo to F13-63.